# Как добавить класс «active» на главной странице domain.com?

Tags: php

Приветствую, подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью этого примера

```
   <li <?= false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php') ? 'class="active"' : '' ?> >
```

выполнить добавление класса на главной странице "domain.com" а не на "domain.com/index.php"

Comment: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI' == '/index.php') {  $text = 'class="active"' }

Comment: Спасибо, а конкретно на приведенном примере можете показать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ такой

```
<li <?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' 
  || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php') ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!